# Transaction Control Statements in Procedure Executed as Definer

Tags: postgresql

We are just getting started with Postgres and started to explore its features. One of the things we noticed is the limitation to execute a commit within a transaction if the procedure is executed as the definer (with SECURITY DEFINER in the procedure definition).

I saw another post about this and one of the suggested workaround is like to have a wrapper procedure (executed as invoker) where these transaction control statements could be done following a procedure call (executed as definer). What we would like to do though is be able to control it within the transactions in the sub procedure especially if doing autonomous transactions.

Do we know why Postgres has this limitation?

We tried controlling the access privileges on the schema and make sure that only certain users can execute functions or procedures within the schema. We also set session IDs, played around with user/group, ACLs and set table policies for row level security but there is still this question on where to do the commits.

But we expect to be able to control commit and rollback directly within the procedure executed as definer and not from the invoker of the procedure call.

Comment: Why would you want to attempt to commit a transaction in the middle of a procedure? It hasn't even completed yet.

Answer (score 0):

That is explained in `ExecuteCallStmt` in `src/backend/commands/functioncmds.c`:

```
/*
 * In security definer procedures, we can't allow transaction commands.
 * StartTransaction() insists that the security context stack is empty,
 * and AbortTransaction() resets the security context.  This could be
 * reorganized, but right now it doesn't work.
 */
```

Indeed, `StartTransaction` has

```c
    /* SecurityRestrictionContext should never be set outside a transaction */
    Assert(s->prevSecContext == 0);
```

This can be traced back to [commit eedb068c0a7474fb11d67d03b0a9e1ded5df82c4](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=commit;h=eedb068c0a7474fb11d67d03b0a9e1ded5df82c4):

```
Make standard maintenance operations (including VACUUM, ANALYZE, REINDEX,
and CLUSTER) execute as the table owner rather than the calling user, using
the same privilege-switching mechanism already used for SECURITY DEFINER
functions.  The purpose of this change is to ensure that user-defined
functions used in index definitions cannot acquire the privileges of a
superuser account that is performing routine maintenance.  While a function
used in an index is supposed to be IMMUTABLE and thus not able to do anything
very interesting, there are several easy ways around that restriction; and
even if we could plug them all, there would remain a risk of reading sensitive
information and broadcasting it through a covert channel such as CPU usage.

To prevent bypassing this security measure, execution of SET SESSION
AUTHORIZATION and SET ROLE is now forbidden within a SECURITY DEFINER context.

Thanks to Itagaki Takahiro for reporting this vulnerability.

Security: CVE-2007-6600
```

So the intention is to prevent privilege escalation attacks.

You may want to read [this mailing list thread](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/27798.1199856124%40sss.pgh.pa.us) that offers more detailed explanations.

Comment: Thanks @Laurenz Albe for sharing that information. I guess what we have done thus far would work in terms of setting the right level of access privileges between the invoker and definer and as well as access privileges to the schema and different objects.

Bergi: We are currently on Oracle but exploring Postgres as an option to replace Oracle. We have a sub procedure in Oracle where we needed to do like autonomous transaction and the reason why I asked about being able to issue a commit in a separate transaction while the main transaction is still being worked on by the main procedure.

Comment: There are no autonomous transactions in PostgreSQL. The best way is to move transaction management to the client code. The next best way is to use `dblink` to fake autonomous transactions.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your suggestions Laurenz. I am also reading about pg_background extension as another option I guess..